# Set one active screen from two?

Tags: java, blackberry

I run background service within this application and gui part.

I have two screens in my application, one is registration screen the other one is updatestatus screen, after my registration is complete i have to view only one screen no matter when the user is want's to get into application.

I would really appreciate a small piece of code that does that.
Thank you in advance.

```
public GuiApplicationUI() {                     
            if (!isOk) //if registered then enter the updatescreen
                    pushScreen(new RegisterScreen());
            else
                pushScreen(new UpdateScreen());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is registrations screen pushed only once throughout life of app on device? And If I am correct, once user successfully finishes registration, you don't want to push it again ever. Is this the case?

Comment: Your question would probably be better received if you show your work: what have you tried, why is it not working for you?  This community often responds negatively to questions that sounds like "hey, could you do my work for me?"

Comment: first of all i didn't asked for do my work i just asked how do i do it and short code snippet wouldn't kill any one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my applications, I use [Persistence Store](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.7api/net/rim/device/api/system/PersistentStore.htm) to store any state of the app. Once user has successfully registered, update state in persistence store to "registered". Now whenever you want to push screen, check state of registration from persistence store before taking action.

Comment: Thank you i have did it too and it's works perfectly